# Can you prove that if $3 \mid 2a$, then $3 \mid a$, with prime factorization?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, prime-factorization

The statement goes as following: if $3 \mid 2a$, then $3 \mid a$ and $a$ is an integer. In my approach, I used prime factorization, but is this actually valid? This was my approach:

$$3 \mid 2a \implies 2a = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot k, k \in \mathbb{N}$$

$$\frac{2a}{2} = \frac{2\cdot 3 \cdot k}{2}$$

$$a = 3 \cdot k$$

$$\therefore 3 \mid a$$

Is this valid or am I doing forbidden things here?

Comment: Why would you imply that $a=3k$ when that's exactly what you're looking to prove..

Comment: $3$ divides $2a$ only means that $2a=3k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes you can prove with the prime factorization, just by stating that the multiplicity of $3$ is the same in $a$ and $2a$.

Comment: It might be useful to know (for context later) this is a simple case of Euclid's Lemma, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma, with the fact that $3 \nmid 2$.

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Ah, that's a really bad mistake I made :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $2a=3k$ implies 
$$ a=3a-2a=3(a-k)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $\,\ 3\mid 2a,3a\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid 3a\!-\!2a = a.\ $ **QED** $\ $   We used Bezout $3 - 2 = 1.\,$ This generalizes:

---

Generally $\,c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid a\ $ if $\ b,c\,$ are (Bezout) coprime  $\ jb+kc = 1\,$

**Proof** $\ \ c\mid abj,akc\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid  a(jb+kc) = a\ \ $ **QED**

More generally, using basic gcd laws (notably gcd distributive law)

$\qquad\quad\  c\mid ab,ac\ \Rightarrow\ c\mid (ab,ac) = a(b,c) = a$

Note that none of the above proofs use prime factorization.

Answer (score 0):

First note that 1 = 3 - 2.  Multiply by a: a = 3a - 2a.  If 2a = 3n (for some n), then a = 3a - 3n = 3(a - n).  Hence 3 | a.

This generalizes to other prime pairs: When p, q are distinct primes, GCD(p,q) = 1, hence there are (signed) integers m, n such that 1 = pm + qn.  Multiplying both sides by 'the other value in the product' *(here a)* isolates that value on the left and produces an expression divisible by p or q *(depending on which is 'the first value in the product')* on the right.

This also generalizes to algebraic structures more general than numbers.  It does NOT work when the dividing item *(here 3)* is NOT prime!

Comment: The final sentence is false. As I explain in my answer, the proof needs only *coprimaility* of $\,b,c,\,$ so it certainly *does* work in many cases when $\,c\,$ is not prime.